# How to set the label and limits of specific plot in the subplot?

Tags: python, plotly-python

**First question:**
Using plotly.py does somebody know how to set axis label and axis limits using `make_subplots`?

Using matplotlib I would use `ax.set_xlabel()` and `ax.set_xlim()` but I can't find how to do it using plotly even after reading [link1](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Scatter.html) and [link 2](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/).

Here is a minimal example in case it helps:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

xv = np.linspace(0, 1, 99)
yv = 1-np.exp(-xv)

fig = make_subplots( rows=1, cols=1 )
                    
fig.add_trace( go.Scatter(x=xv, y=yv, mode='markers', name='Exp' ), 
               row=1, col=1 )
fig.show()
```

**Second question:**
Let's say I have 3 rows and 3 cols, how do I specify that I want to modify the axis of the plot in the second row and the second column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First answer:** You can simply use:

```
fig.update_xaxes(title="Date", range=[0,0.8])
```

**Full code:**

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots


xv = np.linspace(0, 1, 99)
yv = 1-np.exp(-xv)

fig = make_subplots( rows=1, cols=1 )
                    
fig.add_trace( go.Scatter(x=xv, y=yv, mode='markers', name='Exp' ), row=1, col=1 )

fig.update_xaxes( title="Date", range=[0,0.8] )

fig.show()
```

[image]

**Second answer:** to update the x-axis of any plot in the subplot, you should specify only in which row and column the plot is. That's it!

```
fig.update_xaxes(title_text="xaxis 4 title", range=[0,10], row=2, col=2)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works great! But how does 'update_xaxes' work if I have more subplots? Let's say I have 3 rows and 3 cols, how do I specify that I want to modify axis of the plot in second row and second from left?